# Find the union of request data and response data with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am sending request data like this

```
{
 "1": "a",
 "2": "b",
 "3": "c",
 "4": "d",
 "5": "e",
  "array": [
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "ONE",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "TWO",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "THREE",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "FOUR",
      "Value": "1"
    }
]
}
```

Response data is received through the API like this

```
{
"Code": "00",
"Msg": "SUCCESS",
"Data": [
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2",
  "c": "3",
  "d": "4",
  "e": "5",
  "f": "6",
  "g": "7",
  "h": "8",
  "array": [
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "ONE",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "TWO",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "THREE",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "FOUR",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "FIVE",
      "Value": "0"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "SIX",
      "Value": "0"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "a": "9",
  "b": "10",
  "c": "11",
  "d": "12",
  "e": "13",
  "f": "14",
  "g": "15",
  "h": "16",
  "agreements": [
   {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "ONE",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "TWO",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "THREE",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "FOUR",
      "Value": "0"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "FIVE",
      "Value": "0"
    },
    {
      "GroupID": "NUMBER",
      "CodeID": "SIX",
      "Value": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I wrote a code like this that compares data and data and selects only the data that matches the requested data.

I put all the response data in the list and wrote the code like this

```
List<user_model> list= new List<user_model>();
List<user_model> list2= new List<user_model>();

    foreach (user_model um in list)
    {
        if (um.array[0].Value == param["7"].ToString() &&
            um.array[1].Value == param["8"].ToString() &&
            um.array[2].Value == param["9"].ToString() &&
            um.array[3].Value == param["10"].ToString())
        {
            list2.Add(bm);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to code my code more concisely through lambda expressions?

Comment: I am not sure if that code is valid C# (looks like C++) but it is clearly no C code. Please don't add unrelated language tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bm is a typo you could do something like

```
list2.AddRange( 
    list.Where( um =>
        um.array[0].Value == param["7"].ToString() &&
        um.array[1].Value == param["8"].ToString() &&
        um.array[2].Value == param["9"].ToString() &&
        um.array[3].Value == param["10"].ToString() 
    ) 
);
```

If your values are arrays and not strings then you need to do an array compare, how you do this is up to you, e.g.

```
um.array[0].Except(param["7"]).Count() > 0

um.array[0].SequenceEquals( param["7"] )
```

there may be a point where it makes sense to pull this comparision logic out into a separate comparer class. There will be existing answers detailing that

Comment: 'List<user_model>' does not contain a definition for 'Append' and does not have an accessible extension method 'Append' that accepts a first argument of type 'List<user_model>'. Make sure you have a using directive or an assembly reference.   
I get an error, what's the problem?

Comment: sorry i think its actually AddRange, answer updated

Comment: Thanks for the very accurate answer
I have one more question What to do when the requested data is an array instead of a string? I'd like to see your question edited again.

Comment: @totmoto the best way to say thank you is to mark the answer that helped you as "Accepted".

Comment: @totmoto not sure what you mean exactly but i've updated the answer

Comment: @Aero9999  list2.AddRange( 
    list.Where( um =>
   um.array[0].Except(param["7"]).Count() > 0
   um.array[0].SequenceEquals( param["7"] )
    ) 
);                                                                                                                                       I want to check if this expression is correct

Comment: I want to find the same data as the array in the request data among the two data in the response data and put only one data in the list

Comment: That is not a valid bit of code, if you want two checks in your call to Where() you need to put && in there